# Vector erase function not working properly

Tags: c++

I am trying one of the practice problems on hackerrank.
I'm aware there is a better way to do it, but I would like to know why this way didn't work to understand it better.
The vector erase function seems to work as intended until the last couple of times and then erases at the wrong index, even though nothing changes.

debugger output:
1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, //what is currently in the vector 
Delete indx 0 & 1 //The first pair that I will erase and increment count
3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, //continue...
Delete indx 0 & 4
1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
Delete indx 0 & 2
2, 3, 3, 3, 
Delete indx 1 & 2 //says to delete the first and second three
3, 3, //it looks like the 0th and some other index was erased instead
Delete indx 0 & 1
count returned is: 5
let me know if I can add to this question to make it better, thanks

```
int i, count = 0;

for (i=0;i<ar.size()-1;i++)
{
    for (int j=i+1;j<ar.size();j++)
    {
        if (ar[i] == ar[j])
        {
            ar.erase(ar.begin()+i-1);
            ar.erase(ar.begin()+j-1);
            count++;
            i=-1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ar.size()== 0)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Because you are running forward through the vector, when you delete at index 0, every thing shifts back one position, so what was at index 1 is not at index 0 and what was at index 2 is now at index 1 and so on. So your subsequent deletes are not deleting the items at the index you expect because those items have changed index.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but in the debugger output you can see it works fine for the first three iterations before doing what you described. I have it reset to the beginning after it erases/shifts by setting i to -1

Comment: it only appears to be working correctly, because of the way the initial data is sequenced. Actually, one thing that bothers me with the code, you have `ar.begin()+i-1` if `i` is 0 then you will be indexing before the beginning of the iterator, I suspect that is going to cause you problems with other inputs, I have not run this but it might just be luck that it works with these inputs?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you only need the count of pairs (considering the removals).

```
for(int i = 0; i < ar.size() - 1; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < ar.size(); j++){
        if(ar[i] == ar[j]) {
            ar.erase( ar.begin() + j );
            count++; 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you only need to perform 1 call of erase (which is slow, considering it moves all the elements in the right of the deleted element 1 slot to the left).

If you have big vectors, also consider not using `ar.size()` all the time (at least in `j` loop, since in `i` loop it's kind of essential). Try `for(int j = i + 1, len = ar.size(); j < len; j++)`.

Comment: But if the don't use `ar.size()` and they erase items, whoosh! Off the end of `ar` and unto the badlands of undefined behaviour. Might be better to do this with iterators rather than indexes.

Comment: Did you even try the code? The indexes won't be messed up this way. Also I forgot to add a break after it finds a match. Try the code, the indexes should be fine.

Comment: `j < len` `len` never changes. If you have ten items in the `vector`, `len` is ten. `len` stays ten. Remove 2 items from `ar` and `ar[j]` when `j` is 9, is booms-ville, man.

Comment: len will be recalculated always it is needed, since in the moment it deletes something, the loop using len breaks.